# Get different content from same URI

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am developing a blog system using Laravel and showing content based on URI segment. My segment is 3 and this segment is, post TITLE.

Problem is once a post title is "test" and another post has same title, "test" then system is showing only 1 post where there are 2 post actually.

How could I show the both post with same URI.

Example:
URI : example.com/article/test

Expected Content :

Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1

Example:
URI : example.com/article/test

Expected Content :

Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2

Comment: We cannot help you without code.

Comment: Could you kindly help if you have similar thing or you know how to meet the above requirement ?

Comment: So you basically have two (or more) articles named "test" and if this is the case you want to display all matching articles on the same page?

Comment: well, URL could be same but content need to be different.

Comment: Can you show your code?